# Using Predicate in Swift to Query Table from Azure Mobile Services

Tags: ios, azure, swift

I am trying to query my Azure Mobile Services using Predicate in Swift.
However, I am executing the query and nothing is returned. Even if I change the column name to something that don't exist, I am not returned any error message from Azure Mobile Services and no records are retrieved.

Is anyone able to spot anything obviously wrong with what I am doing here? Appreciate any guidance you can give. Here is some of the relevant code:

```
var usersTable : MSTable?
var records = [NSDictionary]()
let userID = UIDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
let userCheckPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userid == %@", userID)
usersTable!.readWithPredicate(userCheckPredicate) {
            result, totalCount, error  in

    if error != nil {
                println("Error: " + error.description)
                return
            }
    records = result as [NSDictionary]
    println("Information: retrieved %d records", result.count)
```

I also tried enclosing the %@ with single quotation marks, with no different outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The NSPredicate syntax was incorrect.

My predicate needed to say:

```
let userCheckPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userid == [c] %@", userID)
```

Comment: Hi, Can we predicate on date , say get the items only for past 2 days               NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *twoDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-2*24*60*60];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSString *toString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:twoDaysAgo];
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(updatedAt>= %@)",toString]; but i am getting error from azure services      Found operand types 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'GreaterThanOrEqual'.

Comment: Arun Gupta.   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventToDate > %@", argumentArray: [Date()]).       Oyvind Vik.  Your original predicate works for me,  not sure why you had to change it...